# Wordpress Translate Explaination

Tags: functions

I'm dissecting Wordpress's default theme TwentyThirteen in attempts to learn more about wordpress.

I ran into a function call that I simply don't understand even after reading the short codex description.

I would greatly appreciate insight on why the programmers/developers  decided to format the edit link in this way.

```
edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'twentythirteen' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have two main [functions for translations](http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers), `_e()` and `__()`. The first *prints* the value, and the second *assigns* the value.

As we are feeding a value to a function, we don't print or `echo` (the `e` in the function) anything, so we use the assignment function `__()`.

What happens is that [`edit_post_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/edit_post_link) will receive the translated string for `'Edit'`.

As for the function, `edit_post_link($link, $before, $after)`, we could do something like:

```
edit_post_link( 'Edit this', '<strong>', '</strong>' );
```

And it would make the edit link with a custom, untranslatable, string in bold. To learn more you can [dig in the archives of this site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation?sort=frequent&pageSize=50).

Comment: I having a very hard time understand what translations are used for and why they are useful.

Comment: Well, they're useful for the rest of the world who doesn't speak English ;) If you're not gonna use it and it's not a theme that you will release to the public, it doesn't matter, you can safely change all `__('something','twenty')` and `__(etc)` for your own texts.

Comment: *facepalm* I didn't realize translate was actually translating the word to different languages, I had assumed that translate was some kind of programming term that translated string into a more syntactically acceptable string. I have no idea why I thought this.

Comment: well, fp surely happens to all of us ;) I've added a useful search query to the answer.